# Using 2 Datasets in One Single SSRS Chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a table containing Terms and their associated definitions within a database.  Most of the terms contain definitions, but some are not defined, and are NULL.

I have two SQL Queries two differentiate the two sets of terms, which follow:

Terms with Definitions:

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
FROM INFA_META.IMW_ELEMENT E left Join INFA_META.IMW_ELMNT_ATTR EA
ON E.ELEMENT_UID = EA.ELEMENT_UID
WHERE E.CLASS_UID = 35947 AND CLASS_ATTR_UID = 35951 AND EA.ELMNT_ATTR_VALUE != 'NULL'
ORDER BY E.CLASS_UID;
```

Terms without Definitions:

```
SELECT Count (*)
FROM INFA_META.IMW_ELEMENT E left Join INFA_META.IMW_ELMNT_ATTR EA
ON E.ELEMENT_UID = EA.ELEMENT_UID
WHERE E.CLASS_UID = 35947 AND CLASS_ATTR_UID = 35951 AND EA.ELMNT_ATTR_VALUE = 'NULL'
ORDER BY E.CLASS_UID;
```

Currently, these are both listed in separate datasets within an SSRS report.  I am trying to display the count of terms w/ definitions vs the count w/o definitions on a pie chart.  I cannot for the life of me figure out how to display information from two separate datasets into the one chart.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

When you create your tablix/chart in your report you will give it a DataSetName.   Let's say it's "DataSet1".   By default, any data fields you reference in the Tablix will come from DataSet1.

If you want to access data from DataSet2 in the same tablix, you can do it with an expression like this:

```
=Sum(Fields!MyFieldName.Value, "DataSet2")
```

However, this assumes that you don't need the data from DataSet2 to be related to other data on the same row from DataSet1.   If you DO need to relate Dataset2 to Dataset1 on a row-by-row basis, then you need to google the LOOKUP function in SSRS.  (I've never needed it before, so I don't have any examples handy).